# Can service/daemon app use 'common' instead of 'tenant-id' when obtaining token from Azure AD v2.0 endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a daemon app that can perform actions on user inboxes in multiple tenants. Once an admin from a tenant gives the app the required permissions, it should be able to access users inboxes in that tenant. I am doing the following now.

1. Get consent from admin

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fredirect.test.com`
2. Global Admin from a tenant (e.g. `myutils.onmcirosoft.com`) gives required permission.
3. Get access token by using `common` instead of `tenant-id`

   `curl -X POST _https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client-id}&client_secret={clientsecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

   It gives a access token.
4. Access messages of `admin@myutils.onmicrosoft.com` using the token obtained in step 3.

   `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/admin@myutils.onmicrosoft.com/messages`

   Above curl request gives the following `404` response: 

   `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   Cache-Control: private
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Content-Type: text/plain
   request-id: e602ada7-6efd-4e18-a979-63c02b9f3c76
   client-request-id: e602ada7-6efd-4e18-a979-63c02b9f3c76
   x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_22","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
   Duration: 1537.3097
   Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 09:31:08 GMT`

In step 3 if I replace `common` with `tenant-id` of `myutils.onmicrosoft.com` it is working.

Is `common` supported with Azure AD v2.0 endpoint? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365) link says `common` is not supported for v1 endpoint. Is it the same for v2.0 endpoint as well?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the token at e.g. https://jwt.io? I am not 100% sure this is not impossible, but in my opinion it does not make sense to call common for a token. When you access Microsoft Graph API, which tenant's data should you get back? If your app is single-tenant, then the answer is simple. But in a multi-tenant case, specifying the tenant id will definitely be mandatory.

Comment: Hi , My app is mult-tenant. The reason I wanted to try with 'common' is. If it works, with the same token I can send requests for multiple tenants. If it does not I would have to get token separately for each tenant. The page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds suggests it would work. The examples there uses 'common' with 'adminconsent'. Guess it should be updated

Comment: If there is admin consent, that is an authorization URL, not a token URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on Nan Yo's answer, the reason you need the `tenant-id` is due to Graph API itself being a multi-tenant.

Without a `tenant-id`, Graph would have no way of knowing which tenant to route your calls too. For example,`/users` returns a list of users but without a `tenant-id` there is no way to determine which tenant it should pull the users from.

When you use `authorization_code` or `implicit` grants, it uses the user's credentials to determine which tenant calls should be routed too. With `client_credentials` you don't have those credentials to pull those routing queues from.

You can however determine the tenant id during Admin Consent. Along with the `admin_consent` result, it also returns the `tenant`. For a multi-tenant service you would need to store that id to use when obtaining a token prior to making a call to Graph.

Comment: Hi Marc, I am doing POST operation only (Step 3). I am following steps from this page 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds' . It uses 'common' to get authorization and token. But while using the token to get messages I received the '404' response. I feel the page needs to be updated. Looks like 'common' is not supported for a multi-tenant daemon app

Answer (score 1):

When using the client credentials flow in Azure AD V2.0, you need to specify the actual tenant that you want a token for. Otherwise , even you get an access token , you will find no application roles include in the access token . An access token will issued from one tenant and could access resource of that tenant , it is impossible to use one access token to query resources of multi tenants .

Please acquiring your token **not** from `/common/oauth/v2.0/token` endpoint , use `/{tenent-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint with the tenant id  .

Please click [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/auth_v2_service.md) for more details .